# check entity parameter route

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

How can i check if element exists with this method :

```
#[Route('/edit/{id}', name: 'edit')]
public function edit(Category $category): Response
{
    //some code
    return $this->render('someView.html.twig');
}
```

Like with this method :

```
#[Route('/edit/{id}', name: 'edit')]
public function edit($id, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository): Response
{
    $category= $categoryRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    if (!$category) return $this->redirectToRoute('category_list');
    return $this->render('someView.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because [`ParamConverter`](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html) handle it for you. If it doesn't find the object, you will have a 404 error in production.

If you absolutly want to customize a redirection or whatever, you'll have to do it manually like your second example.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, if the id parameter does not match with a category object, a not found exception will be thrown automatically, while in your second example you're doing it manually to redirect the user depending of the category.